# Go and Python HMAC libraries give different results

Tags: python, go, hmac

I am trying to authenticate using HMAC/sha512 API key scheme.

Here is the example Python code, which works fine:

```
import urllib, urllib2
import json
import time
import hmac, hashlib
import sys
api_key = "J88PJQEG-LKKICZLN-3H33GWIB-97OGW8I5"
secret = "b9f2e97c5c43e8e759c06219b37fce78478985ae4b0176d47182419c434567405a9386a854bca5d068135d1163d3f1cc9b877cd5d95d03c9d100be6ffcaac864"

# cmd = sys.argv[1]
# args = json.loads(sys.argv[2])

def auth_request(command, args):
    args = [("command", command), ("nonce", 3000000000)]
    post_data = urllib.urlencode(args)
    print post_data
    sign = hmac.new(secret, post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
    print sign
    headers = {
        'Sign': sign,
        'Key': api_key
    }

    ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', post_data, headers))
    return ret.read()

print auth_request("returnBalances", {})
```

And now my Go implementation:

```
const (
    public_api_url  = "https://poloniex.com/public"
    private_api_url = "https://poloniex.com/tradingApi"
    pubkey := "J88PJQEG-LKKICZLN-3H33GWIB-97OGW8I5"
    privkey := "b9f2e97c5c43e8e759c06219b37fce78478985ae4b0176d47182419c434567405a9386a854bca5d068135d1163d3f1cc9b877cd5d95d03c9d100be6ffcaac864"
)
func CallPrivate(method string, args map[string]string) dynjson.DynNode {

    if args == nil {
        args = make(map[string]string)
    }
    v := make(url.Values)
    v.Set("nonce", "3000000000") //strconv.Itoa(int((time.Now().Unix()))*1000))
    v.Set("command", method)
    for k, val := range args {
        v.Set(k, val)
    }
    final_url := private_api_url + "?" + v.Encode()
    log.Println(final_url)
    client := &http.Client{}
    post_data := v.Encode()
    secret_bytes, err := hex.DecodeString(privkey)
    check(err)
    sighash := hmac.New(sha512.New, secret_bytes)
    sighash.Write([]byte(post_data))
    sigstr := hex.EncodeToString(sighash.Sum(nil))
    log.Println(sigstr)
    j, err := json.Marshal(args)
    check(err)
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(j)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", final_url, buf)
    check(err)
    req.Header.Set("Key", pubkey)
    req.Header.Set("Sign", sigstr)
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    check(err)
    defer res.Body.Close()
    if res.StatusCode != 200 {
        log.Println("bad status code")
        log.Printf("%s", res)
        panic(errors.New(res.Status))
    }
    res_body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    check(err)
    //log.Printf("%v", res_body)
    return dynjson.NewFromBytes(res_body)

}

CallPrivate("returnBalances", nil)
```

Right now I am stuck calling out to the python implementation which is not a pretty solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python `dict` is an **unordered** mapping type.

```
>>> args = {}
>>> args['command'] = 'command'
>>> args['nonce'] = 10000
>>> list(args)
['nonce', 'command']  # <--- Iterating dictionary will yield in different order
                      #      with item insertion order
```

[`urllib.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) not only accepts a dictinoary, but it also accept a sequence of key-value-pair sequences. You can use it to guarantee the order of output:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlencode({'command': 'command', 'nonce': 10000})
'nonce=10000&command=command'
>>> urllib.urlencode([('command', 'command'), ('nonce', 10000)])
'command=command&nonce=10000'
```

Alternatively, instead of `dict` (`{}`), you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which remembers key insertion order.

**UPDATE**

In the Go code, `command` post data is set with `method` instead of `command` parameter.

```
v.Set("command", method)
                 ^^^^^^
```

**UPDATE2**

Python code uses the hex string `secret` as is:

```
sign = hmac.new(secret, post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
```

while the Go code decode it before use it:

```
secret_bytes, _ := hex.DecodeString(privkey)
sighash := hmac.New(sha512.New, secret_bytes)
```

Do the same way as the Python code:

```
sighash := hmac.New(sha512.New, []byte(privkey))
```

**UPDATE3**

- Go code does json marshal for post_data, but Python code does not.
- You need to set header in Go code: "Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

---

Here's the modified Go code that will work:

```
func CallPrivate(method string, args map[string]string) {
    if args == nil {
        args = make(map[string]string)
    }
    v := make(url.Values)
    v.Set("nonce", "3000000000") //strconv.Itoa(int((time.Now().Unix()))*1000))
    v.Set("command", method)
    for k, val := range args {
        v.Set(k, val)
    }
    final_url := private_api_url
    post_data := v.Encode()
    sighash := hmac.New(sha512.New, []byte(privkey))
    sighash.Write([]byte(post_data))
    sigstr := hex.EncodeToString(sighash.Sum(nil))

    client := &http.Client{}
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(post_data))
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", final_url, buf)
    req.Header.Set("Key", pubkey)
    req.Header.Set("Sign", sigstr)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    res, _ := client.Do(req)
    defer res.Body.Close()

    res_body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    log.Printf("%s", string(res_body))
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it - the signatures are different even when the argument order is the same.

Comment: @user165730, To be sure, try with hard-coded literal: `command=command&nonce=10000` in both languages. (I suspected that the value of the `method` in the Go code is not same as the `command` parameter).

Comment: They are definitely the same string. I have a suspicion it is something to do with encoding when going to/from []byte.

Your update is a good catch but that's my mistake simplifying the code for the question - in the real code it uses the right argument.

Comment: @user165730, Could you provide a minimal **working** code so that I can figure out what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited OP to include the real thing, including dummy API keys you can use. The problem is that the Go version returns an unhelpful "invalid command" error from poloniex, which I'm 99% sure is actually a bad signature because the requests look identical otherwise.

Comment: @user165730, Unlike Python code, Go code missing `import` statements. Please provide code that I can compile.

Comment: @user165730, Never mind. I managed to compile it, debug it. Please check out the UPDATEs.

Comment: Done. Now that is a blast from the past!